# How do I fix the image size when changing to another image?

Tags: javascript, html, css, slideshow

I am learning how to do a slideshow with CSS, HTML and Javascript, everything seems to be fine but when I click on next or prev the current image gets bigger and it stays on the screen for a few seconds. I am using images with different sizes, but I added a width on CSS -> `img{width:100%;}`. It could be something related with the margins as well but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

Here is some code that might help you understand the problem:

```
figure
{
    position:absolute;
    opacity:0;
    transition:1s opacity;
    margin:0;
    border-left:solid 2px black;
    border-right:solid 2px black;
}

figure.show
{
    opacity:1;
    position:relative;
    transition:1s opacity;
    margin-right:15%;
    margin-left:15%;
}
```

Also there is a space between the image and the bottom div. I am doing this on c9.io and I don't have this problem there, could it be something on codepen that is causing it?
You can check the code out here: http://codepen.io/iikinz/pen/BiLeJ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your images are getting bigger cause you are removing the show class and the show class has the margins.

Move:

```
margin-right:15%;
margin-left:15%;
```

out of figure.show and into figure.

--UPDATE--
Here it is: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/Cuikc

--UPDATE--
This works for most of your images but a couple of them are smaller than the rest so those appear to get smaller when changing slides.  The ideal solution would be to just make sure they are all the same size.  Plus it will keep them looking clear since they won't have to be stretched.

Answer (score 1):

About the gap under the image, it's displayed inline :

```
img {
  display: block; /* this will fix bottom gap */
  width: 100%;
}
```

About your images size :

Just use images of the same size will fix your situation. Otherwise try forcing them with css

```
figure img {width:1280px;height:960px;margin-right:15%;margin-left:15%;}
```

About i can i do the transition and more ... well, not to sound arsh or nothing, but .. keep studying. You are quite asking too much in a single question.